# How do I open up a download dialog box using Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, text-to-speech

I'm trying to let the user download an mp3 file after a text-to-speech convert using gTTS. The flash message appears but the download dialog does not open.

Here is the Python code:

```
def mytts():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['text']:
            flash('Text needed to proceed', 'error')
        else:
            text_input = request.form['text']
            tts = gTTS(text=text_input, lang='en')
            f=TemporaryFile()
            tts.write_to_fp(f)
            flask.send_file(f,as_attachment=True,attachment_filename="MyTTSOutput.mp3", mimetype="audio/mpeg")
            f.close()
            flash('Successful Text-to-Speech Convert')
            return redirect(url_for('mytts'))
    return render_template('mytts.html')
```

HTML Code (the form part only):

```
    <form action="" method=post class="form-horizontal">
        <h2>Convert Text To Speech</h2>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <textarea name="text" rows=10 class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter text to be converted here" required>{{ request.form.text }}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">CONVERT!</button>
          <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">HOME</button></a>

        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result of `send_file`. It generates a response object, Flask can only do something with that object if it's returned from the view function.

```
with TemporaryFile() as f:
    tts.write_to_fp(f)
    return send_file(f, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename="tts.mp3")
```